# Principal Ultrafilter implies Isomorphic Ultraproduct

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathfrak{F}=\{X\subseteq \mathbb {N} \mid 17\in X \}$ (Note that $\mathfrak {F}$ is principal ultrafilter) and:

Let $\mathfrak{N}$ be the standard model for arithmatic and
$\mathfrak{N}^*=\mathfrak{N}^{\mathbb{N}}/ \mathfrak{F}$

Can someone explain (**in details**) why $\mathfrak{N} \simeq \mathfrak{N}^*$?

Comment: Try writing an isomorphism.

Comment: Ok. If we will label the models in the product as $\mathfrak{M}_{i}$, then some formula $\varphi$ is true in the ultraproduct iff the set of indices $i$ such that $\mathfrak{M}_{i}\vDash \varphi $ is in the ultrafilter, i.e contains 17. Therefore some formula is true in the ultraproduct iff it's true in the 17th model which is $\mathfrak {N}$. Not sure if it's enough or if it's formal enough.

Comment: It's not formal enough; and it just shows that the models are elementarily equivalent (which is not enough to conclude isomorphism). Take the definition of elements of $\frak N^*$ and find a function map such element to a natural number, and make it so the map is an isomorphism.

Comment: Ok, so let $\pi: \prod \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb {N}$ . Then $\pi(f)(i)=f(17)$ . In words - $\pi$ is the projection to the 17th coordinate$

Comment: But $\frak N^*$ is not the product, it's a quotient of the product. So you have to pull the projection to the quotient, since clearly the projection is not injective (the cardinality of these two sets is not the same!). But you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a simple lemma saying that if F is an ultrafilter on I and $G \in F$, then $F|G$ is an ultrafilte on G, where $F|G = \{ X \cap G : X \in F \}$.
2. One proves then a bit more involved statement that 
   $(\prod_{i\in I} A_i)/F \simeq (\prod_{i\in G} A_i)/(F|G)$.
3. The claim follows then taking $G = \{j\}$ - the 17th coordinate in your case. The right-hand-side in 2. becomes then isomorphic to $A_j$.